# Save git pull origin and branch

Tags: git

When I run git pull it says

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> main
```

When I run git pull origin main then it works as intended. How do I make git pull automatically use origin and main?

Answer (score 0):

Just as advised by the GIT in your above image, run the following command:

`git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/main main`

Then try running `git pull`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to set an upstream branch is to use the `--set-upstream-to` option when pushing the branch to the remote repository for the first time:

```
$ git push --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch>
```

A shorter synonym is the `-u` option (instead of the self-explaining but clunky `--set-upstream-to=`):

```
$ git push -u origin <branch>
```

If the remote counterpart branch already exists or if you want to change the upstream branch, you can use the `git branch` command:

```
$ git branch -u origin/<branch>
```

You can read more about upstream here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch/2.19.0